# How to mock http request in flutter integration test?

Tags: dart, flutter, mocking, mockito, flutter-test

I'm trying to do so using Mockito, this is my test:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:utgard/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  group('Login flow', () {

    final SerializableFinder loginContinuePasswordButton =
        find.byValueKey('login_continue_password_button');

    FlutterDriver driver;

    setUpAll(() async {
      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });

    tearDownAll(() async {
      if (driver != null) {
        //await driver.close();
      }
    });


    test('login with correct password', () async {
      final client = MockClient();

      when(client.post('http://wwww.google.com'))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"title": "Test"}', 200));

      globals.httpClient = client;

      await driver.enterText('000000');
      await driver.tap(loginContinuePasswordButton);
    });
  });
}
```

And this is my http request code:

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> post({
  RequestType requestType,
  Map<String, dynamic> body,
}) async {
  final http.Response response =
      await globals.httpClient.post('http://wwww.google.com');

  print(response);

  final Map<String, dynamic> finalResponse = buildResponse(response);

  _managerErrors(finalResponse);

  return finalResponse;
}
```

And here I have the global:

```dart
library utgard.globals;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

http.Client httpClient = http.Client();
```

However I continue to receive http errors, that indicates to me that the http wasn't replaced by the mock.

Comment: I made a suggestion answer below, but it's kind of long shot, because I don't have the code of `    final SerializableFinder loginContinuePasswordButton =
        find.byValueKey('login_continue_password_button');`. There's a small chance the problem lies in there.

Comment: Hi Felipe, could you find a way to mock the dependencies in Flutter integration testing? How about using `DataHandler` as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/mocking-integration-tests-with-flutter-af3b6ba846c7)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found was to define the mock in *test_driver/app.dart* and call the `runApp` function after that:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:utgard/business/config/globals.dart';
import 'package:utgard/main.dart' as app;

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  final MockClient client = MockClient();
  // make your mocks here
  httpClient = client;

  runApp(app.MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```dart
      when(client.post('http://wwww.google.com'))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"title": "Test"}', 200));
```

try `any` and then assert it later

```dart
        when(
          mockHttpClient.send(any),
        ).thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"title": "Test"}', 200));
// ...
        final String capt = verify(client.send(captureAny)).captured;
        expect(capt, 'http://wwww.google.com');
```

There's a small chance the call param is not exactly what you mock, so go with `any` is safer.

Answer (score 2):

We don't see the code you're testing, but it's unlikely that it is going to make this request :

```
client.post('http://wwww.google.com')
```

It is anyway a good practice to use mock json files, and you don't want to change the request anytime those mock files change.

I recommend you to use [Mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) instead of Mockito.

That way, you can simulate any call with `any` :

```
// Simulate any GET :
mockHttpClient.get(any()))

// Simulate any POST :
mockHttpClient.post(any()))
```

Here's the complete solution :

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}
class FakeUri extends Fake implements Uri {}

void main() {

  setUp(() {
    registerFallbackValue(FakeUri()); // Required by Mocktail
  });
  tearDown(() {});

  MockHttpClient mockHttpClient = MockHttpClient();
  group('Login flow', () {
    test('login with correct password', () async {
      when(() => mockHttpClient.get(any())).thenAnswer(((_) async {
        return Response(mockWeatherResponse, 200);
      }));
    
    // Call the functions you need to test here

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is *not a way* to mock services (including HTTP calls) in a Flutter integration test. I can't emphasize this enough: it is *not possible*.

<sub>(If you're writing a widget test or unit test, mocking is straightforward. You can write your own mocks or use mocktail or mockito.)</sub>

For the purposes of this answer, you're in an integration test if you're using `IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`—that is, if the test is running on a simulator or a physical device. In this case, the app code and the test code are running on different isolates, so nothing you do in your test code can affect what's happening in the app code and vice versa. They are walled off from each other.

Back in the days of `flutter_driver`, you could use a DataHandler to pass messages back and forth between your test and the app as described [in this article](https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/mocking-integration-tests-with-flutter-af3b6ba846c7). `flutter_driver` is obsolete now and there is no equivalent for the `integration_test` package; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76852), which at present is still open.

The Flutter team's concept of integration tests is that they must mirror exactly what the app does when an end user is using them. Ergo, no mocking allowed. All HTTP requests are stubbed (returning HTTP 400) in widget/unit tests, but they work as normal in integration tests.

If you need repeatability in an integration test, you'll have to figure it out at the environment level, outside of Flutter.