# Mocking Http Client calls in flutter test

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

Friends

I am building flutter code that is centred around API calls made with the package [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

To do integration tests and widget tests I have to mock calls that use [http.Client](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client-class.html)

For my testing I wish to change as little of my application code as I can.  If it were up to me I would not mock the API calls, but the flutter testing framework will not allow that.  If there is a way to tell the flutter testing framework to allow me access to the network that would obviate my need for this question.

The methods to do what I am trying to do that I have found  (e.g: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62189542/4326664), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758200/4326664)) all involve modifying my application code.  I am not going to modify application code, that works, to test it.  That is putting the cart before the horse.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58368507/4326664) that includes code do do what I want with the package `path_provider`.

Essentially

```
  test("Test mocking path_provider", () async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    const MethodChannel channelPathProvider =
        MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/path_provider');
    channelPathProvider.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      return "."; // <-- Breakpoint here.  This is called
    });
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print("dir: $dir");
  });
```

This works well, and is what I need, but for a different package.

I copied the code as faithfully as I can (making some guesses I will detail after) and it does not do what I need.  I am doing something incorrect:

```
  test("Test mocking http", () async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    const MethodChannel channelPathProvider =
        MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/http');
    channelPathProvider.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      return Response("Body", 200); // <-- Break point here.  Not called
    });
    var client = Client();
    Uri url = Uri.parse("https://example.com/");
    Map<String, String> headers = <String, String>{
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    };
    var response =
        await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: '{"foo":"bar"}');
    print("response: $response Status: ${response.statusCode}");
  });
}
```

My guesses were two:

- The argument to: `MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/http');` I see this all over, but i have seen no explanation of how the argument string 'plugins.flutter.io/http' is built.  What I am doing seems logical
- The mocked method call.  In the `path_provider` example it returns ".".  The call is expecting a Directory.  That takes a string as a constructor, so???  I return `Result("body", 200)`.  If the mocked function were being called, this might be a problem.  But it is not so is not, yet.

Comment: If you're using `package:http` and want to mock `http.Client`, you should 1. Make your code use a specified `http.Client` object if specified. 2. Make your tests pass an instance of the [`MockClient` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html).

Comment: @jamesdin thatis very unhelpful.  I know I can do that, I have done that, that is not the problem.

Comment: Your code shows you creating a normal `http.Client`, not a `MockClient`.  Otherwise please clarify exactly what problem you are encountering.  A minimal but complete example that can reproduce your problem would help others help you.

Comment: janesdin: I said "For my testing I wish to change as little of my application code as I can".  Is that unclear?  I used the example `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` where the communications with the package was intercepted in the test without changing code.  Still unclear?

Answer (score 2):

Your `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` example is irrelevant; `package:http` is not a Flutter plugin and does not use method channels.

If you care only about Dart VM builds (i.e., not Dart for the Web), then `package:http` is built upon `dart:io`'s `HttpClient`, which can be overridden via [`HttpOverrides`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpOverrides-class.html).

However, manually using `HttpOverrides` is a lot of work.  The third-party [`fake_http_client`](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_http_client) package does it for you:

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:fake_http_client/fake_http_client.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> doHttpWork() async {
  var httpClient = http.Client();
  var response = await httpClient.get(Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/'));
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    print('Failed: ${response.statusCode}');
    return;
  }

  print(response.body);
}

void main() async {
  await doHttpWork(); // Prints normal content.

  await io.HttpOverrides.runZoned(
    () async {
      await doHttpWork(); // Prints fake content.
    },
    createHttpClient: (_) => FakeHttpClient(
      (request, client) {
        if (request.uri == Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/')) {
          return FakeHttpResponse(
            statusCode: 200,
            body: 'hello world!',
          );
        }
        return FakeHttpResponse();
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

If you care about Dart for the Web, then `HttpOverrides` won't work.  In general, most people using `package:http` should be using its [`MockClient`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) class.  Using it might involve making some changes to existing code, but it usually can be very minor and non-intrusive.  For example, you could modify the example above to be:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/testing.dart' as http;

http.Client theHttpClient = http.Client();

Future<void> doHttpWork() async {
  var response = await theHttpClient.get(Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/'));
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    print('Failed: ${response.statusCode}');
    return;
  }

  print(response.body);
}

void main() async {
  theHttpClient = http.MockClient((request) async {
    if (request.url == Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/')) {
      return http.Response('hello world!', 200);
    }
    return http.Response('', 404);
  });

  await doHttpWork(); // Prints fake content.
}
```

Comment: "Your getApplicationDocumentsDirectory example is irrelevant; package:http is not a Flutter plugin and does not use method channels."   That is helpful.  Clearly I was confused.  That will explain why the method did not work.